# Make WHERE condition from parameter string mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a parameter :param that has different amount of elements in different executions.
:param value looks smth like **"1,23,456"**

I need to make a WHERE cause with LIKE

Hardcoded it would be look like:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE field LIKE '1%'
    OR field LIKE '23%'
    OR field = '456'  -- maximum length of filed value equals 3
```

The biggest problem is we don't know amount of elements in parameters.
Any ideas?

Comment: Look into the Concat command to do dynamic column names.  Citation located -> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp .  Also its very expensive to search every column looking for a value, instead of searching a single column for a value.

Comment: As an example, it would be better to search for a specific column to get a key to then use that key from that column to look up the EXACT value in another table.   I don't know if that makes sense to you, but if at all possible, re-design your system to work like that, as once you get many columns and many rows you will get horrible latency doing dynamic column searches.

Comment: You could also do `field REGEXP '^(1|23|456)'`

Comment: @easleyfixed concat won't help in that situation. 
And yeah it's a must to have that kind of flexibility.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks!

Actually, with your suggestion,  ```filed REGEXP CONCAT('^(',REPLACE(:param, ',', '\\d*|'),'\\d*)')``` works the way it should

Comment: I guess so, I was thinking of cases where the column name might change but the formula for the procedure was the same, such as use concat to search for a dynamic column name, instead of searching EVERY column.

Comment: HOLD UP ..I WAS CORRECT.. the answer did require the use of ConCat ... I knew I was onto something ....

Answer (score 0):

We can do it as follows :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM myTable t
inner join (
  select * 
  from json_table(
    replace(json_array('1,23,456'), ',', '","'),
    '$[*]' columns (id varchar(50) path '$')
  ) j
) as s on s.id = t.field
```

`Json_table` to return rows from the param then using `inner join` to get the expected result

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ypb9FsGg)